# how to ignore/avoid/skip child collection from a LINQ query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

I have a collection :

```
order
o1
o2
o3
```

I have orderItem collection :

```
OrderItem orderId
oitem1    o1
oitem2    o1
oitem3    o1
oitem4    o2
oitem5    o3
```

now I am selecting orders with line, but how do I **skip/avoid/ignore the child collection from LINQ**

I don't want **orderItems** with my **orders** .

Comment: Provide more details with an example and what have you tried, this is simple just remove it from the select statement, you may want to create anonymous type

Comment: Much more detail required, I'm afraid. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Hi, I don't want to see the child items at all in the LIST I am trying to fetch